# Schema Help; Updating through joins; SQL

Tags: sql

below is some code that I have typed as well as some notes pertaining to said code, I tried to provide a thorough description of the three tables involved.

This is the select/join I used to ‘link’ the three tables that will be involved in completing this process.

```
select * from SMI.dbo.API api
left outer join FM.dbo.MP mpi on api.PEIDS = mpi.PEID
inner join SMI.dbo.SIP sip on mpi.FIDID = sip.FIDID
```

API- Has a PEID, MaidenName, DOB, and Place of Birth

MP or MPI- Has a PEID, FIDID, FI, MI, and Last names for a Bride & Groom.

SIP- Has a FIDID, this is the destination table

Within the API, each record has an individual’s PEID, as well as their maiden name (If they’re a female) their DOB, and their Place of Birth. Also included within this table is a ‘Gender’ Field.. (I.E. M, F, U)

Within the MPI field, each record has the same PEID for each individual; however it also houses a FIDID that is tied to each Record. Therefore in this table, you will find that the number of total records is nearly double the overall totals of the other two tables.. This is because you are receiving a record for both the Bride and the Groom.

Within the SIP you will find the majority of the index information pertaining to each Marriage, most importantly the FIDID.

Scope: The ultimate goal for this query is to insert the MaidenName, BirthDates, and BirthPlaces, into the SIP table, all the while differentiating between M & F.

With this being said, since there is no direct link between the destination table (SIP), and the source table (API) I felt that joining API and 
(MPI) would be the best method of ‘bridging’ this gap.

Since I only have a PEID to go off of, I will need to look at the ‘Gender’ field as well to determine whether or not the particular record is pertaining to the bride or to the groom(M or F), after locating a specific record’s PEID & Gender, the query should then move on to the next step of locating the FIDID from (MPI) via the PEID, and it should then insert the MaidenName, BirthDates, and BirthPlaces into SIP accordingly.

I realize the syntax on the code below is completely wonky. I mainly typed it out while attempting to visualize what I needed done.

```
USE [SMI]
GO
SELECT  * from SMI.dbo.API api
left outer join FM.dbo.MPI mpi on api.PEIDS = mpi.PEID
inner join SMI.dbo.SIP sip on mpi.FIDID = sip.FIDID   
  CASE 
  ((( WHEN api.PEIDs = mpi.PEID and mpi.FIDID = sip.FIDID 
   (THEN 
   Update SIP
     set groomdob = api.birthdate, GroomBirthPlace = api.birthplace
     where api.gender like 'M')  
     and
     ((Update SIP
     set bridedob = api.birthdate, BrideBirthPlace = api.birthplace, BrideMaidenName = api.birthlastname
    where api.gender like 'F' ))
     ELSE null)))
       END
FROM SMI.dbo.API api
ORDER BY PEIDs ;
GO
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance y'all have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE SMI.dbo.SIP s
inner join (select * from SMI.dbo.API api
left outer join FM.dbo.MP mpi on api.PEIDS = mpi.PEID
inner join SMI.dbo.SIP sip on mpi.FIDID = sip.FIDID WHERE api.gender like 'm') m
on s.FID = m.FID
SET s.groomdob = m.birthdate, s.GroomBirthPlace = m.birthplace

UPDATE SMI.dbo.SIP s
inner join (select * from SMI.dbo.API api
left outer join FM.dbo.MP mpi on api.PEIDS = mpi.PEID
inner join SMI.dbo.SIP sip on mpi.FIDID = sip.FIDID WHERE api.gender like 'f')  as f 
on f.FID = s.FID   
set s.bridedob = f.birthdate, s.BrideBirthPlace = f.birthplace, 
s.BrideMaidenName =f.birthlastname
```